# Is it legal to embroider tag information directly onto my dog's collar in Oregon?

Tags: dogs, identification, legal

My wife and I recently adopted our first dog and one thing that I've been concerned about is the noise of jingling tags.

I know that there are various silicone holders and slide-on options available but I thought I could really simplify things and save a couple dollars if I just embroider the text from the various tags onto the collar itself.

Is this legal (in the state of Oregon)?

Comment: Try asking this question on another StackExchange Site :https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: try asking your vet about this he/she should know what the rules and regulation are or call the local shelter and ask.

Comment: your question is area spesific so it will probably be closed,a Q&A should be helpful for as many people and pets as possible.

Comment: @trond I included the Oregon information because there seem to be overlapping factors: State and county ordinances as well as the national rabies registry, all of which have their own tag (or at least tag *info* since they seem to share a tag with info on both sides). It occurred to me that there might be an issue at the higher level but not the lower or vice versa.